# Problem on a query with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hierarchy

I have a very simple scenario, using NHibernate:

- one abstract base class "animal";
- two concrete subclass "cat" and "dog" with discriminator column (1 for dog and 2 for cat);
- one normal class Person;

Person have a many-to-one of animal.

I want retrieve a list of person with a dog.
How can I do this?
thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, something like this :

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
    .CreateCriteria("Animal")
        .Add(Expression.Eq("discriminatorField", 1))
    .List<Person>();
```

above is "Criteria API" but you can use "HQL" it's more something like this :

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("from Person pers where ");
query.Append("from Animal ani ... and :wichAnimal");
query.Append("and cus.IsActive = :wichAnimal");

IList<Person> list = session
    .CreateQuery(query.ToString())
    .SetInt16("wichAnimal",1)
    .List<Person>();
```

HTH